# Отключить предложение сохранять пароль HTML

Tags: html, браузер

На сайте есть [форма регистрации](http://adv.pr-slot.com/registration), в хроме после ввода всех данных и submit'а браузер предлагает сохранить логин и пароль. Причем логин он определить не может и получается вот такое (скрин).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На форме стоит свойство `autocomplete="off"`.

Подскажите, как это отключить, еще в форме авторизации это норм, но при регистрации сохранение не должно работать.

Answer (score 2):

Вообще сохранение паролей в браузере - это фишка самого браузера.
И для каждого клиента определяется настройками его браузера.
Ну как вариант используйте XHR запросы.
Нет отправки формы - нет предложения о сохранении пароля! ))

Comment: Есть формы регистрации на других сайтах  где браузер не предлагает сохранять данные, в свойствах я ничего не заметил что бы могло отключать запоминание. Но они же как то это делают.

Comment: В любом случае это костыль. Сохранить пароль или нет - это настройка браузера, ее не поменять. Какой использовать костыль решать Вам)) я предложил xhr еще есть ответ ниже)

Answer (score 2):

## Неправильный способ

Чтобы не дать сохранить пароль, просто не отправляйте форму. Используйте XMLHttpRequest для отправки данных формы. Пользователи вас возненавидят, но кого же это волнует?

## Правильный способ

Сделайте нормальную форму с логином, чтобы браузеру не сносило мозг. Если как логин будет использоваться email, то и поставьте его первым и дайте полю нормальное имя (ну или чего там Хром хочет). Запоминание паролей — это удобно.

P. S. Пихать в форму регистрации кучу опциональных полей — дурной тон. Отпугивает пользователей от регистрации.

Comment: принцип регистрации в будущем будет переделан. Что бы сначала вводился только почтовый ящик. а остальные данные уже когда пользователь войдет в панель управления через ссылку в письме. Но это будет в будущем. Хотя если взять как пример вот эти формы https://signup.live.com/signup или эта https://appleid.apple.com/account ребята вообще не парятся на тему ввода 9000+ полей в форме

Comment: @BigTree Они не парятся, потому что регистрацию не обойдёшь. :)

Comment: Неправильно, это предлагать сохранять пароль при его вводе не для входа, а для изменения личных данных, например удаления анкеты или изминении имени. Моих пользователей нужно уберечь от кривых или случайных действий коллег, семьянинов, детей и т.д. Один раз запомнилось и любой, кто зайдет в открытый комп, сможет одним кликом изменить или удалить важные данные. Так что для входа в аккаунт, это пожалуйста, а для изменения важных данных только ручной ввод пароля! Кто забыл пароль, посмотрит его через браузер, но случайные люди или действия не испортят кашу.

Answer (score 1):

Есть очень кривой хак с добавлением невидимого инпута в самом начале формы и убиранием самого инпута с паролем непосредственно перед отправкой формы. Хром не находит инпут с паролем и не пытается его сохранить:

```
var password = $("#password");
$("#hiddenPassword").val(password.val());
password.val("");
password.attr("type", "text");

myForm.submit();
```